# Displaying data from xml in php

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have a problem with downloading data from xml file to php. The cells are numbered and email addresses are not arranged in a column. Can anyone help me?

**new.xml**

```
   <Table ss:DefaultColumnWidth="54" ss:DefaultRowHeight="14.25">
<Column ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s74" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="29.25"/>
<Column ss:StyleID="s74" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="192"/>
<Column ss:StyleID="s115" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="194.25"/>
<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="69.75"/>
<Row ss:Height="15">
<Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s166">
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s166">
<Data ss:Type="String">email</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s166">
<Data ss:Type="String">Alias</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s90">
<Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s118">
<Data ss:Type="String">adam</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s104"/>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell ss:Index="4" ss:StyleID="s122" ss:HRef="mailto:adam@test.com.pl">
<Data ss:Type="String">adam@test.com.pl</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell ss:Index="4" ss:StyleID="s122" ss:HRef="mailto:adam.b@test.com.pl">...</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell ss:Index="4" ss:StyleID="s122" ss:HRef="mailto:grp@test.com.pl">
<Data ss:Type="String">grp@test.com.pl</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell ss:Index="4" ss:StyleID="s122" ss:HRef="mailto:shop@test.com.pl">
<Data ss:Type="String">shop@test.com.pl</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell ss:Index="4" ss:StyleID="s123"/>  
</Row>
</Row>
```

here is my php code:

```
    <?php
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom -> load("new.xml");
$data = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Data'); 
echo( "<table><tr>");
$n = 0;
foreach($data as $node)
{ 
if($n % 3 == 0) { echo '<tr>'; }
echo( "<td>". $node -> textContent . "<td>");
if(++$n % 3 == 0) { echo '</tr>'; }
}
echo( "</tr></table>");

?>
```

// edited the xml file

Comment: When you say "email addresses are not arranged in a column", are you doing any transformation after the download? Try to make your post as complete as possible (read about how to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Have looked at [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) Extension?

Comment: wants the data display them:                                     in the first column of numbers in the second address in the third e-mail aliases